# What's a word or phrase that means "saved in the wrong file format"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I'm writing a report on a website. There are files that were saved in the wrong format which has reduced the quality of the images. How can I say this, but still sound professional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a single word to state all this. You'd have to try a sentence. The example below has been written so that it sounds "professional" :

> Image contained in incorrect format. Quality consequently reduced.

Comment: Technically the extension is correct for the file format. The file format is not optimal... actually, that's pretty good: "not optimal file format"

Comment: Putting that into a sentence, that could read "Not optimal file format. Quality reduced" That'd sound pretty good. Love that suggestion

Comment: I don't think that you'd use 'contained' in this way to describe this kind of problem - I'd say "The images were saved in the wrong format, which reduced their quality", or if you want to be a little more precise "the image files were saved in the wrong format...."

Comment: I'd suggest:

"This sub-optimal format will lower the image quality."

Comment: @Kyle Pearson - the phrase 'sub-optimal' is not helpful here IMO - it depends on what you're trying to optimize. It's quite possible that the images were saved in a format that made the files very small, but which made the images themselves look poor. So if small size was important, then the files were optimal.

Comment: I can see your point.  In the context of the report, though, the meaning of "optimal" is probably quite clear.

Answer (score 3):

For a nice, neutral lead-in to a recommendation that the image file format should be changed, I'd say something like

> The image file format chosen does not give the best image quality.

(The format isn't "wrong", since the images still display correctly; it's just not the best choice for the job.)

Comment: +1 for clarifying that the choice of format largely comes down to a trade-off between filesize and image quality. It could easily come across as impolite to tell someone that they made a "wrong" choice of format, just because you favour quality over size more than they do.